# Prepend all variable and functions names in C++ file

Tags: c++, parsing, prepend

I am looking for a way to prefix a word to ALL variable and function names in a C++ file.

Here is a small example:

```
float myFloat = 3.14159;

void loop() {
 int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  delay(1);
}
```

should be turned into

```
float KEYWORDmyFloat = 3.14159;

void KEYWORDloop() {
    int KEYWORDsensorValue = analogRead(A0);
    Serial.println(KEYWORDsensorValue);
    delay(1);
}
```

EDIT:
The first idea I had was to use GCC to transcribe the code into an Abstract Syntax Tree and parse the file while replacing all declarations etc.
Things failed miserably since I have to replace the names and functions without compiling the code.

Comment: Hm. Getting the function names would be easy in vim: :%s/\a*()/KEYWORD&/gc. Not sure of an elegant way to get the variable names, but you could replace using a large disjunctive regular expression with your variable names and then use the same replacement as above.

Comment: This doesn't look like a C++ or gcc question.

Comment: I think it can be done relatively easy with libclang.

Comment: @Almo it is C++-specific if the tool's output needs to be 100% correct (i.e. it needs to understand C++ syntax so it doesn't prepend KEYWORD to something other than a variable or function name).

Comment: is wrapping it in a namespace not viable?

Comment: this is exactly what namespaces are for.